# Wordpress search post_title only

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to limit a search on Wordpress (3.0.4) only to the post_title.
Is there a way to do that without modifying the core files?

Thanks for your help!
Cheers

Comment: [limit-search-results-to-custom-post-type](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-search-results-to-custom-post-type)

Comment: no, this is to limit the search to a certain post_type! What I need to do, is to limit the search to the post_title... any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468804/make-wordpress-search-only-in-post-title">post</a>. You'll need to modify the functions.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make wordpress search only in post title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468804/make-wordpress-search-only-in-post-title)

Answer (score 0):

The guys at WPSNIPP seem to have made available a function that you can add to your theme's function.php file

http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/limit-search-to-post-titles-only/