# Make WordPress search only in post title

Tags: wordpress

I have a new website and I want to modify WordPress Mystique theme 3.0 in order to search only in post title.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 47):

There are numbers of articles available in Google if you have searched before you posted.

[WordPress search only in post title](http://www.google.com.pk/?q=wordpress%20search%20only%20in%20post%20title#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=wordpress+search+only+in+post+title&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7033e3bc2fb13717&biw=1024&bih=667)

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

Add this code to your **functions.php**

Comment: This is great, how con you add the tags to this query... i cant find a way to

Comment: Brilliant!!! It would be amazing if it searched the title, tags and categories!! :D