# WordPress custom post type search not filtering search based on input

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, custom-post-type

If you go to: http://joshuajohnson.co.uk/tarva/centres/

At the moment I am using the following query in my search file:

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'centre', 
  'paged' => $paged,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => 6, //Limits the amount of posts on each page
  'post_title' => 'LIKE %'.$_POST['s'].'%' 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However, if you search anything, the results page shows just first 6 posts of the post type ‘centre’. I’m using a while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); loop to filter results.

I gather that it isn't using the input from the search field, but am not sure why? Any ideas?

A gist with the related pages: https://gist.github.com/jshjohnson/cb8c1000f8d0d9b16935

EDIT: If I remove 'posts_per_page' from the query entirely, the search yields no results every time

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be searching using the 's' argument.

```
's' => $_POST['s']
```

not

```
'post_title' => 'LIKE %'.$_POST['s'].'%'
```

There are also a number of posts about this:

- [Make wordpress search only in post title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468804/make-wordpress-search-only-in-post-title)
- http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/limit-search-to-post-titles-only/

Comment: That returns all the entries of the post type as well :/ I don't really want to just search the post title either - I have included custom fields in the search index.

Comment: Here is an example Gist of a search I just wrote last week.
https://gist.github.com/dcooney/8944353

Comment: That gist searches first by $term using 's' and then by custom field 'organization'. I then merge the arrays and using a 'post_in' to pull from the custom post type. Also, I am using GET not POST