# How to make wordpress search only search WooCommerce product title

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make my site search only a woocommerce product title (currently, when I search, the result comes gives me from both description and title).

I tried the Relevanssi plugin and WooCommerce Filter Search, but that doesn't seem to work, so now i'm looking for another idea...

I'm using this theme [link](http://teslathemes.com/demo/wp/sportify/?page_id=20) and that red search at the top navigation

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting, for a better readability.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468804/make-wordpress-search-only-in-post-title

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I am seeing at [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-relevanssi-a-better-search-search-titles-only), you need to be using relevanssi premium and disable post content in searches.

Not Tested.